# gb4e: overwrite italics in first line

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

Dear Stackexchange community,

For my dissertation I use gb4e for my examples. To get the first line in italics, I use the following code:

```
\let\eachwordone=\itshape
```

In some examples, however, I include words in brackets, quotation marks, etc. I would like these to not be in italics. However, I have not found any working solution to this. Does anyone have an idea?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{gb4e}
\let\eachwordone=\itshape

\begin{document}
The following examples are in Swahili. In (1) I'd like the parenthesis not to be in italics, in (2) the quotation marks.

\begin{exe}
\ex[*]{\gll nyumba i-na-on-ek-a (na) wa-tu\\
house(9) 9-\textsc{prs}-see-\textsc{neut}-\textsc{fv} (\textsc{com}) 2-person\\
\glt intended: \lq (A/the) house is seen by people.'}
\ex[]{\gll a-li-sem-a kwamba \lq\lq na-m-ju-a"\\
1-\textsc{pst}-speak-\textsc{fv} \textsc{comp} \textsc{1sg.prs}-1-know-\textsc{fv}\\
\glt \lq He said \lq\lq I know him."'}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Thank you so much!

Comment: for manual adjustment you can try `\textup{(na)}` etc.

Comment: OMG, that's was so obvious that I did not see the forest for the trees. Thanks!

Comment: Or you just use `\emph{}` for these parts, then the italics is reversed.

Comment: That also works, but I prefer the \textup{} variant. This way, if I should change my mind about the italics or have to use the normal font for editorial reasons, the command will be redunant, but not cause any confusion. Thank you anyways for your comment.